# Структура бд для перевода переменных

Tags: база-данных

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Надо бы сделать var_key уникальным,как лучше поступить,создать еще одну таблицу с ключами и в поле var_key хранить айди?

Comment: Уникальный ключ можно сделать по 2м полям.. я бы сделал по lang and var_key

Comment: ALTER TABLE `table_name` ADD UNIQUE `unique_index`(`var_key`, `lang`);

Comment: Спасибо за совет

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL  позволяет создавать ключи по множеству полей что удобно когда комбинация должна быть уникальной.

```
ALTER TABLE 
    `table_name` 
ADD UNIQUE 
    `unique_index`(`field_1`, `field_2` ...);
```